# Declaration 2d array containing multiple objects for graph plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I using [igDoughnutChart](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.1/ui.igdoughnutchart) for my web-page, I want a graph which shows the following hierarchy

- source of attack (inside)

  - login abuse
  - dos
  - spyware
  - worm
- outside attackers

  - spying
  - social attacks

The current object array looks like (also [demo](http://jsbin.com/oXuMAzU/4/edit))

```
var data = [
              { "attacksource": 43, "attacktype": 60, "AT":"DoS","Label": "iNISDE" },
              { "attacksource": 29, "attacktype": 40, "AT":"login abuse","Label": "outside" } 
];
```

**I want to change this to do following:-** (also shown above)

Where I have a parent and child values in 2d array so above code is to transform as

```
  var data = 
        [
            [{"attacksource": 43,"Label":"Inside"}],
            [
                 {"attacktype": 13,"Label":"dos"},
                 {"attacktype": 13,"Label":"virus"}...
            ]
        ];
```

I'm not sure If I have initialized / assigned 2d using **objects**  correctly.I appreciate If someone can look at the code, and let me know if I'm doing this right.

**UPDATE**

The jsbin example is just something to illustrate my requirements for the new code. For e.g `"Label":"virus"` is currently hardcoded, in real code (which I cannot do on jsbin) is I will get the values from DB.

**[VISUAL EXAMPLE](http://lh6.ggpht.com/-WsYb0mzuKs0/Umm4pmcykTI/AAAAAAAARoQ/I4NLhJ2whng/s1600-h/image9.png)**

Comment: The initialization params for the chart in your jsbin example are all messed up - mismatching square and curly brackets etc., making it hard the figure out what you wanted them to be.

Comment: @John-NotANumber let me revise it wait

Comment: @John-NotANumber does it make sense now.

Comment: Can you at least post "before" data that actually maps to your "after" data. Otherwise how is anybody supposed to figure out which property ends up where?

Comment: @MattBurland do you mean "before" and "after" in regard to parents and child hierarchy? If yes I have tried to explain above or you want visual representation. Please explain.

Comment: In your supposed "target" you have, for example, `"Label":"virus"` the string `"virus"` isn't even in your source data so how do you expect anybody to understand where it comes from? You also have, for example `"dos"`, but you have `"DoS"` in the original. Are they supposed to map to each other? At least be consistent.

Comment: And you have `Inside"` (presumably missing a `"`), but `"iNISDE"` in your source? Again, are they the same thing? How is anybody other than you supposed to know??

Comment: @MattBurland I'm sorry for so much ambiguity, I have clean up my question. I'm hoping its better then before now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the chart you are trying to use support what you want to do. That being said there is somewhat of a hack to make it work:

```
$(function () {

  var data = [
    { "label": "Inside", "attacks": 8 },
    { "label": "Outside", "attacks": 6 },

    // Inside 
    { "label": "Dos", vector: "Inside", "dummyValue": 6 },
    { "label": "siem", detect: "Dos", "detectValue": 3 },
    { "label": "user", detect: "Dos", "detectValue": 3 },

    { "label": "Worm", vector: "Inside", "dummyValue": 2 },
    { "label": "siem", detect: "Worm", "detectValue": 1 },
    { "label": "user", detect: "Worm", "detectValue": 1 },

    // Outside
    { "label": "Spying", vector: "Outside", "dummyValue": 3 },
    { "label": "siem", detect: "Spying", "detectValue": 1.5 },
    { "label": "user", detect: "Spying", "detectValue": 1.5 },

    { "label": "Social", vector: "Outside", "dummyValue": 3},
    { "label": "siem", detect: "Social", "detectValue": 1.5 },
    { "label": "user", detect: "Social", "detectValue": 1.5 },
  ];

  $("#chart").igDoughnutChart({
    width: "100%",
    height: "550px",
    innerExtent: 6,
    series:
    [
      {
        name: "Attack Type",
        labelMemberPath: "label",
        valueMemberPath: "attacks",
        dataSource: data,
        labelsPosition: "center"
      },
      {
        name: "Attack Vector",
        labelMemberPath: "label",
        valueMemberPath: "dummyValue",
        dataSource: data,
        labelsPosition: "center"
      },
      {
        name: "detect Vector",
        labelMemberPath: "label",
        valueMemberPath: "detectValue",
        dataSource: data,
        labelsPosition: "center"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

The order of the `data` and `series` arrays matter (not completely, just partially). Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dixonj16/qYyZ7/4/) that demonstrates this. Disclaimer: I'm not saying this will always work, as it makes the big assumption that igniteUI will always parse and display the data in the same way.

Also I'm not familiar with the library but I would bet there is a way to customize the colors of each section of the chart. If so you could just make the color a function that returns a color based on the `vector` property.

Some alternatives:

- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut)
- [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) - this would be my preferred approach. Browse the gallery, there a few examples that apply here.

Comment: thank you for the excellent help. However, the order for me is important the graph should appear hierarchical children (attack types) inserting attack source (internal) parent information. I have update [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qYyZ7/3/) but I'm afraid the math dist in not maintained as you can see with the second ring (dos) exceeding its parent range. Is there a such can be fixed?

Comment: I updated the code and link above. The key is in the making it line up the way you want is in the values.

Comment: thanks I was very clumsy in adding those numbers. I'm confident now thanks to your help I can do what i need to get the code running in production. One aspect, I want to touch is regarding coloring something I want to achieve but in graident look I also shared the link at end of my question for it. Sadly the support to display such gradient for this plugin is not supported for javascript. Does js have a native code/method to make gradient colors? thanks

Comment: the link for gradient code for same plugin is [link](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/marina_stoyanova/archive/2013/10/24/how-to-build-xaml-doughnut-chart.aspx)

Comment: For the most part you will be limited by what igniteUI supports, especially since it draws the chart on a canvas. See the alternatives in the answer above for more control.