# How to convert object array into 2d array of parent child hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, json

Using this declaration for multidimensional object (shown below) can I make attacksource of label type "**inside**" to contain multiple children e.g **"dos","login abuse"**

```
var data = [
              { "attacksource": 43, "attacktype": 60, "AT":"DoS","Label": "iNISDE" },
              { "attacksource": 29, "attacktype": 40, "AT":"login abuse","Label": "outside" } 
];
```

What I have tried using js is as

```
var data = 
        [
            [{"attacksource": 43,"Label":"Inside"}],
            [
                 {"attacktype": 13,"Label":"dos"},
                 {"attacktype": 13,"Label":"virus"}
            ]
        ];
```

Is this a correct assignment for this task?
Thanks

Comment: duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/q/21486363/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21486363/2359055)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). It's not clear whether you're talking about transforming an existing JSON or building one from scratch.

It's hard to tell you the best way to represent your data without seeing the complete picture. But if a single attack source can have multiple attacks types then one way would be to represent those attack types as an array.

```
[
  {
    "attacksource": 43,
    "label": "inside",
    "attackTypes": [
      {"attacktype": 60, "AT":"DoS"},
      {"attacktype": 18, "AT":"virus"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks. JSON format is used by the jquery charting plugin I'm using. So, using json format can it be transformed into structure I mentioned which is hierarchical?

Comment: i have entered your format but the graph won't render it. http://jsbin.com/oXuMAzU/6/edit

Comment: Using http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.1/ui.igdoughnutchart, you have to enter the data in the format it expects. I'll try to answer the duplicated question.

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes you are right about the plugin documentation. If the format it accepts is json should the change format not work?

Comment: @did you posted a reply on my original question? I think its get missed out somehow , I see in inbox but on link itself? Can you confirm.?

Comment: I did but delected it because it didn't really answer the question. I'm not sure the chart supports what you want to do. There may be a workaround though. I just haven't had time to explore it yet.